# Server code in Javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net, properties, shared

I have:

```
Page.aspx
Page.aspx.vb
TestClass.vb
```

I'm trying to access a shared property of the TestClass class from the Page.aspx.

This code works fine:

```
...
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">

    <% if System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name.ToLower = "pt-br" Then %>
        alert('portugues');
    <% else %>
        alert('ingles');
    <% end if %>

</script>
</head>
...
```

But when I try to access a shared property of TestClass, I get an exception:

```
<% if TestClass.Idioma = TestClass.TipoIdioma.Portugues Then %>
    alert('portugues');
<% else %>
    alert('ingles');
<% end if %>
```

**ERROR BC30451: Name 'TestClass' is not defined.**

This is the class:

```
Public Class TestClass

    Public Enum TipoIdioma
        Portugues
        Ingles
    End Enum

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Idioma() As TipoIdioma
        Get
            If System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name.ToLower = "pt-br" Then
                Return TipoIdioma.Portugues
            Else
                Return TipoIdioma.Ingles
            End If
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: I think maybe we need some more info here.  Where is your TestClass.vb file located? Is it in the App_Code directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new instance of `TestClass`. Try something like this:

```
<script language="JavaScript">

    <%
    Dim tc = new TestClass()
    if TestClass.Idioma = TestClass.TipoIdioma.Portugues Then %>
        alert('portugues');
    <% else %>
        alert('ingles');
    <% end if %>

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear but is your class in a namespace? You may need to import the namespace into your aspx file.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="MyNamespace" %>
```

Comment: It not worked... the same error again.

The "TestClass" class is not the code-behind of the page. I have:

Page.aspx
Page.aspx.vb
TestClass.vb

I'm trying to access a shared property of the TestClass class from the Page.aspx.